# Reduce multiple if statements for class adding (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

My example:

```
var Country = this.value; // here I get "England" or "USA" or "Canada" aso.

if(Country === "England") {
    $("#myDiv > span").addClass("england");
}
if(Country === "USA") {
    $("#myDiv > span").addClass("usa");
}
if(Country === "Canda") {
    $("#myDiv > span").addClass("canada");
}
```

aso.

Is there an easy way to cut this down to one, two lines?

**Just as little update for Keldan Chapman solution:**

If you want to toggle this or dynamical replace the class, you have to remove the classes before, like this:

```
$("myDiv > span").removeAttr('class');
$("myDiv > span").addClass(this.value.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: Do you have only those three countries or you might have more, including ones whose name is composed by more than one word (e.g. "United Kingdom", "Equatorial Guinea", etc.)?

Comment: @secan You are right, I have more then three countries and the name could contain also two or three words.

Comment: In that case, you can start from @keldan-chapman's answer but you'll have to modify it in order to take into account those cases. For exaple, let's say that the HTML class for United Kingdom is `united-kingdom`, it will become: `$("myDiv > span").addClass(this.value.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "-"));` ;)

Comment: Also, for what concerns toggling the class, you do not have to remove the class attribute and then add the desired class; with jQuery you could simply use [toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

Comment: @secan Thx for your extended version (United Kingom). Your .toggleClass() update will not work for example with a select (if you have more then two options), if I am right?

Comment: maybe I misunderstood what you meant but I do not see why it should not work with a `<select>` having more than `<option>`. You can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/btosn8mr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("myDiv > span").addClass(this.value.toLowerCase());
```